# Unable to execute WPS GET request in OpenLayers 3

Tags: openlayers, wps, html5

I am working on a Web GIS development application and using GeoServer 2.11.1, OpenLayers 3 and WPS extension v1.0.0 on Windows 7 and Ubuntu Linux 14.04.

Objective: My objective is to use buffer for spatial analysis (means user will select feature after that user will assign  specific distance say 100m then output will display accordingly) using WPS extension v1.0.0

Development: I am using WPS HTTP GET request to get spatial result. For that I referring following:

http://geoprocessing.info/wpsdoc/1x0ExecuteGETEncoding

Also getting an error as following:

1."Null point exception error". Please check attached screenshot.

[image: WPS error]

Also researching on my side as well as looking  alternative also.

Comment: What have you researched and/or tried?

Comment: I have executed WPS services for  JTS functions like buffer ,length etc.in geoserver..But Output is in xml format ,i want result is in geojson format.

Comment: You have made no mention of GeoJSON in your question so please revise it with more detail about precisely what you want to ask.

Comment: I have  edited my question now..Now Can you help me @PolyGeo.?

Comment: I'm not a potential answerer of your question but I think you may need to edit it some more before it is likely to attract one.

Answer (score 2):

According to table 44 of the WPS [specification](http://docs.opengeospatial.org/is/14-065/14-065.html) you can specify the mime type of your output type.

Checking my local GeoServer's WPS request generator (look under demos) the mime type you want is `mimeType="application/json"`.